# Firebird Shadow on a shared folder (windows os)

Tags: firebird

I'm using isql command to create a shadow file on a shared windows folder!
is this the right command?

```
SQL> create shadow 5 AUTO '\\bma-pc\shadows\PERSO5.SHD';                    
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = HY000                                          
unsuccessful metadata update                                                
-A node name is not permitted in a secondary, shadow, cache or log file name
```

It's fine on a local folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebird prohibits this by default.  It's primarily because it cannot guarantee exclusive access or the order of writes.  Look for the RemoteFileOpenAbility option in firebird.conf to override.  There are comments on why this is risky.

Comment: I'm not sure if that limitation applies to shadows as well, but the error suggests that Firebird is interpreting the provided path as a remote connection string.